# Cannot find file after decompressing from archive in Android

Tags: android, unzip

I am using ZipInputStream and BufferedOutputStream to decompress a file from a zip archive in Android 1.6.  The code runs without exceptions, but when I check the existance of the file, I can't find it.  I am just looking for the filename.  Is there an application directory that stores this file?  Do I need to specify a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Context.getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()).